# What are the WinXP console cursor control characters in c++?

Tags: c++, console, escaping, windows-xp, cursor-position

I need the characters/escape sequences that move the console's cursor position. It would be nice to know the left/right/up/down cursor controls, but if that's not possible, a home (go to the first character of the first line in the console). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any. The Windows console doesn't support such things.
See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for more info.

However, if you just need to return to the beginning of the line, you can just emit a carriage return - try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "foo" << "\r";
    cout << "bar" << "\n";
}
```

It should display  "bar" with no "foo".

Comment: that's better than nothing, but is there any way to get back to the beginning of the console?

Comment: Not using control codes. You can of course write code that uses the console API, which allows you to output anywhere you like.

Comment: I was trying to avoid Conlib. Looks like I'll have to use it.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing is to use the Console API. Here is the [**reference from MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087(VS.85).aspx). I think you wouldn't find the reference very helpful if you don't understand how the console works. The best tutorial I came to read is [**this one**](http://benryves.com/tutorials/winconsole/).

Answer (score -1):

C++ has no standard for cursor control on consoles. That's totally the OS's business.

However, most consoles, inculding XP's support the [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

If that isn't standard enough for you, you can try building [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) on your system.

Comment: XP doesn't support ANSI escape sequences.